# settypeface crashes android when use in baseadapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am using this code

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Declare Variables
            TextView rank;
            TextView country;
          //  TextView population;
            ImageView flag;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
            // Get the position
            resultp = data.get(position);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            rank = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
           country = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);
            country.setText("sfsdfs");
           // population = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);
            // Locate the ImageView in listview_item.xml
            flag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            // Capture position and set results to the TextViews
            rank.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
            //country.setText("????????");
            Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/JameelNooriNastaleeqKasheeda.ttf");
            TextView population  = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.population);
            population.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            population.setText(resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
            // Capture position and set results to the ImageView
            // Passes flag images URL into ImageLoader.class
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG), flag);
            // Capture ListView item click
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // Get the position
                    resultp = data.get(position);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);
                    // Pass all data rank
                    intent.putExtra("rank", resultp.get(MainActivity.RANK));
                    // Pass all data country
                    intent.putExtra("country", resultp.get(MainActivity.COUNTRY));
                    // Pass all data population
                    intent.putExtra("population",
                            resultp.get(MainActivity.POPULATION));
                    // Pass all data flag
                    intent.putExtra("flag", resultp.get(MainActivity.FLAG));
                    // Start SingleItemView Class
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            return itemView;
        }
```

Comment: on the lines where i am using typeface this line crashes the application and application does not run and when i am running the application wirth only Text View population .... the application runs

Comment: error lines are  population.setTypeface(myTypeface); Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/JameelNooriNastaleeqKasheeda.ttf");

Comment: Please share the stack trace / logcat

Comment: 07-27 17:34:46.430    3795-3799/bbc.mobile.sport.ww D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 468K, 20% free 2985K/3724K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 0ms

Comment: This is not what is required. Please share entire logcat so we can see the exact error or exception.

Comment: i cant post all the log the place is too short for this

Comment: 07-28 16:38:15.568    2424-3677/android.process.media I/DownloadManager﹕ Download 94 starting
07-28 16:38:19.078    2424-2428/android.process.media D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 804K, 25% free 3199K/4232K, paused 0ms+10ms, total 10ms
07-28 16:39:04.078    2424-2428/android.process.media D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 627K, 21% free 3350K/4232K, paused 0ms+10ms, total 10ms   
07-28 16:39:34.948    2424-3677/android.process.media I/DownloadManager﹕ Download 94 finished with status SUCCESS

Comment: i think thats the error..it is showing in blue in logcat

Comment: 07-28 16:38:02.958    2424-3433/android.process.media W/ActivityThread﹕ ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());